# Vehicle passenger assignment with capacity constraint

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, graph-theory

### Problem Background

I'm trying to find a solution to the following passenger matching problem:

The network is represented by graph $G=(V,E)$. $V$ is the set of nodes/stations. $p_{ij}$ is the profit of traveling through an edge $(i,j)$. Let $N$ be the number of vehicles, all the vehicles have the same capacity $c$.

At each (discreet) time step, the passengers arrive at their origin station and need to be transported to their destination station. $d^t_{ij}$ is the demand and $f^t_{ij} \le d^t_{ij}$ is the passenger flow, i.e., the number of passengers that are traveling from $i$ to $j$ at time $t$ and are successfully matched to a vehicle. The unmatched passers will leave the system. $X^t_i$ is the total number of available vehicles at station $i$ at time $t$.

#### Objective

The objective is to maximize profit.

**Problem formulation for single occupancy vehicle**

I read a few resources and found the following formulation. However, this formulation assumes that the vehicles are single occupancy.

$$ \sum_{i,j \in V} f^t_{ij}p^t_{ij} $$
$$ 0 \le f^t_{ij} \le d^t_{ij} \quad i,j \in V \quad (1)$$
$$ \sum_{j\in V} f^t_{ij} \le X^t_i \quad i \in V \quad \quad (2)$$

The constraint $(1)$ ensures that the passenger flow doesn't exceed the demand and is non-negative.

The constraint $(2)$  ensures that the number of vehicles doesn't exceed the number of available vehicles $X^t_i$  at time $t$ at station $i$.

As long as the demand is integral, this formulation results in integral passenger flow.

### Question

I'd like to extend the above single occupancy formulation to multi-passenger vehicles. I explored some resources online but the methods focused on individual vehicles instead of stations and were using ILP.

If anyone can point me to some related models and methods, or suggest how to solve this problem I would be grateful.

### Update 1

I thought to add the capacity $c$ to the 2nd constraint as follow:

$$ \sum_{j\in V} f^t_{ij} \le X^t_{i}c \quad i \in V \quad \quad (2)$$

Because I have a limited knowledge of optimization problems, I'd appreciate any feedback regarding this.

Comment: Since the problem assumes that the vehicles have the same capacity, I thought adding the capacity to the vehicle count in constraint no. 2 might help. Can you give me their thoughts on this, please?

Comment: You might want to consider asking on or.stackexchange.com .  That board is focused on optimization problems like this and should have more recommendations.